# how to see the kubernetes container servcie log with restart pod

Tags: kubernetes

Now my kubernetes (`v1.15.x`) deployment keeps restarting all the time. From the log ouput with kubernetes dashboard I could not see anything useful. Now I want to log into the pod and check the log from log dir of my service. But the pod keeps restarting all the time and I have no chance to log into the pod.

Is there any way to login restart pod or dump some file or see the file in the pod? I want to find why the pod restart all the time.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are running the **GKE** and **logging** is enabled you can get all container log by default into the dashboard of stack driver logging.

As of now you can run the `kubectl describe pod <pod name>` to check the status code of the container which got exited. Status code might be helpful to understand the reason for restart, is it due to **Error** or **OOM killed**.

you can also use the flag `--previous` and get logs of restarted POD

Example :

```
kubectl logs <POD name> --previous
```

in the above case of `--previous` your pod needs but still exist inside the cluster.

Answer (score 2):

@HarshManvar is right but I would like to provide you with some more options:

- [Debugging with an ephemeral debug container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/#ephemeral-container): Ephemeral containers are useful for interactive troubleshooting when `kubectl exec` is insufficient because a container has crashed or a container image doesn't include debugging utilities, such as with [distroless images](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless).
- [Debugging via a shell on the node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/#node-shell-session): If none of these approaches work, you can find the host machine that the pod is running on and SSH into that host.

These two methods above can be found useful when [checking logs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/#examine-pod-logs) or [execing into the container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/#container-exec) would not be efficient.